# Move std::vector to std::deque in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, std, stddeque

If I have `std::deque` and `std::vector` and want to combine them to `std::deque`, I can do it the following way:

```
typedef int T; // type int will serve just for illustration
std::deque< T > deq(100); // just some random size here
std::vector< T > vec(50);
// ... doing some filling ...
// now moving vector to the end of queue:
deq.insert( 
    deq.end(), 
    std::make_move_iterator( vec.begin() ),
    std::make_move_iterator( vec.end() )
);
std::cout << deq.size() << std::endl;
```

We know the size of the vector but we can't reserve memory at the end of `std::deque` before using `std::deque.insert(...)`.
So is it the fastest way to move all elements of `std::vector` to the end of `std::deque`? Or did I miss something?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "moving", I think "take the elements from the vector, and put them into the deque"  What you've shown still leaves the moved-from elements present in the vector.

Comment: Is T a type for which moving is supposed to be cheaper than copying? For ints that makes no difference

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
using T = int; // type int will serve just for illustration

std::deque< T > deq(100); // just some random size
std::vector< T > vec(50);
// ... doing some filling ...
// now moving vector to the end of queue:
std::move( 
    begin(vec),
    end(vec),
    back_inserter(deq)
);
std::cout << deq.size() << std::endl;
```

Keep in mind that this still copies the `vector` to the end of the `deq`. It just applies `std::move` on each element of `vec` to the end of `deq`. As long as `T` is just an `int` this is not much different than copying the vector to the end of `deq`.

Comment: I disagree with @MooingDuck, but I see this as equivalent to the OP original post. Don't see either as better it is merely a personal preference.

Comment: I had overlooked the `deq(100)`. Comment removed. I'd switch to a +1, but I can't until the answer is edited :(

Comment: I did some minor changes

Answer (score 0):

I would use `resize` method as follows, because than is `deque` reallocated only once:

```
size_t oldSize = deq.size();
deq.resize(deq.size() + vec.size());
copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), deq.begin() + oldSize);
```

Comment: Reallocation in a deque is not a problem. When it needs more space it adds a new block. The old data is not moved around. This is the advantage of deque over vector and also why it does not have a `reserve()`. The problem with doing a re-size first is that it forces all the elements to be constructed. Then you are doing an assignment operation on each of the elements being copied. This may not make a difference for POD like data but anything complicated this would be inefficient.